# Where can I find details about APPSEC-1793 vulnerability fixed in SUPEE-10266?

Tags: magento-1.9, security

[SUPEE-10266](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-10266) is out with a long list of fixed issues. The severest one to me is "APPSEC-1793: Potential file uploads solely protected by .htaccess", which is a RCE.

I'd like to find out more about the issue to better evaluate my deploy schedule. Is there any in-depth analysis of this specific vulnerability, with attack vectors and mitigation tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that, basically, prior to this patch you could potentially;

1. upload a .jpg in admin area, containing php code (e.g. a $_POST
   listener)
2. then use the CMS pages to {{ ../../../media/cms/img.jpg
   type="core/template" }} - this one is why symlinks got disabled. now
   you can post files to this url, e.g upload to server.

It's possible jpg images contianing code could still be executed from other areas (content sniffing), so they updated the uploader code image validation. So this should be considered in any custom file uploads (e.g frontend) and if the admin area is publically accessible, unauthorised access could be damaging to your store.

Example code is in Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php:

```
                //replace tmp image with re-sampled copy to exclude images with malicious data
            $image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($filePath));
            if ($image !== false) {
                $img = imagecreatetruecolor($imageWidth, $imageHeight);
                imagealphablending($img, false);
                imagecopyresampled($img, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $imageWidth, $imageHeight, $imageWidth, $imageHeight);
                imagesavealpha($img, true);

                switch ($fileType) {
                    case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                        $transparencyIndex = imagecolortransparent($image);
                        if ($transparencyIndex >= 0) {
                            imagecolortransparent($img, $transparencyIndex);
                            for ($y = 0; $y < $imageHeight; ++$y) {
                                for ($x = 0; $x < $imageWidth; ++$x) {
                                    if (((imagecolorat($img, $x, $y) >> 24) & 0x7F)) {
                                        imagesetpixel($img, $x, $y, $transparencyIndex);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (!imageistruecolor($image)) {
                            imagetruecolortopalette($img, false, imagecolorstotal($image));
                        }
                        imagegif($img, $filePath);
                        break;
                    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                        imagejpeg($img, $filePath, 100);
                        break;
                    case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                        imagepng($img, $filePath);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

                imagedestroy($img);
                imagedestroy($image);
                return null;
            } else {
                throw Mage::exception('Mage_Core', Mage::helper('core')->__('Invalid image.'));
            }
```